# int input = 0; Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); input = keyboard.nextInt();

Tags: java

This is a project for my college programming class, I feel like I am almost done with everything as most of the programming is done. The purpose is to play "Nim" or removing the toothpicks until a player removes the last one and that player loses. It may be a simple mistake, but I can't figure out how to get *matches* to show the change throughout the program. I think it may be a simple mistake, but any help would be awesome.

Thanks!

```
package cs160.project2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CS160Project2 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to my game of Nym");
    int playerFirst = 1;     //(int) (Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    int matches;
    if (playerFirst == 1) {
        System.out.println("This time the computer will go first.");
        System.out.println("You may choose the number of toothpicks, This number must be bigger than 20 and less than 30.");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        matches = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (matches <= 20 || matches > 29) {
            System.out.println("sorry but that cannot be an input please enter another number between 20 and 30.");
            matches = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print(matches);
        do {
            computerTurn(matches);
            playerTurn(matches);
        } while (matches > 0);
    }
    if (playerFirst == 2) {

    }
}

public static void playerTurn(int matches) {
    System.out.print("How many toothpicks do you want to remove? ");
    int input = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = keyboard.nextInt();
    while (input<=0||input>=4){
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 3: ");
        input=keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    if (input > 0 && input < 4) {
        matches=matches-input;
    }

}

public static void computerTurn(int matches) {

    if (matches == 1) {
        System.out.println("I, the Computer will take the last toothpick, and YOU WIN!");
        matches = matches - 1;
        return;
    }
    if (matches == 2) {
        matches = matches - 1;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 2 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 1 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there is 1 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 3) {
        matches = matches - 2;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 3 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 2 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there is 1 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 4) {
        matches = matches - 3;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 4 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 3 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there is 1 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 5) {
        matches = matches - 1;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 5 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 1 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 4 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 6) {
        matches = matches - 1;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 6 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 1 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 5 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 7) {
        matches = matches - 2;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 7 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 2 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 5 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 8) {
        matches = matches - 3;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 8 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 3 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 5 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 9) {
        matches = matches - 1;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 9 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 1 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 8 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 10) {
        matches = matches - 1;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 10 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 1 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 9 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 11) {
        matches = matches - 2;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 11 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 2 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 9 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 12) {
        matches = matches - 3;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 12 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 3 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 9 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 13) {
        matches = matches - 1;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 13 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 1 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 12 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 14) {
        matches = matches - 1;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 14 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 1 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 13 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 15) {
        matches = matches - 2;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 15 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 2 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 13 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 16) {
        matches = matches - 3;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 16 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 3 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 13 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 17) {
        matches = matches - 1;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 17 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 1 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 16 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 18) {
        matches = matches - 1;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 18 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 1 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 17 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 19) {
        matches = matches - 2;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 19 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 2 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 17 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 20) {
        matches = matches - 3;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 20 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 3 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 17 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 21) {
        matches = matches - 1;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 21 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 1 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 20 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 22) {
        matches = matches - 1;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 22 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 1 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 21 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 23) {
        matches = matches - 2;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 23 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 2 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 21 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 24) {
        matches = matches - 3;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 24 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 3 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 21 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 25) {
        matches = matches - 1;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 25 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 1 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 24 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 26) {
        matches = matches - 1;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 26 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 1 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 25 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 27) {
        matches = matches - 2;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 27 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 2 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 25 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 28) {
        matches = matches - 3;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 28 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 3 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 25 toothpick left.");
    }
    if (matches == 29) {
        matches = matches - 1;
        System.out.println("My turn. There are 29 toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove 1 of them.");
        System.out.print("Your turn, there are 28 toothpick left.");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Please change the title to something that describes your problem. Then describe that problem in detail in your question. What is the output? What did you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to solve this problem, easiest would be to have your player and computer turn methods return an int, being the number of remaining matches back to your main function. For example:

```
public static int computerTurn(int matches) {
...
...
return matches;
}
```

Another would be to make your matches variable into a static variable, so that all of your methods in your main class should have access to it.
for example:

```
 static int matches;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to my game of Nym");
    int playerFirst = 1;     //(int) (Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    //int matches;
    if (playerFirst == 1) {
        System.out.println("This time the computer will go first.");
        System.out.println("You may choose the number of toothpicks, This number must be bigger than 20 and less than 30.");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        matches = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (matches <= 20 || matches > 29) {
            System.out.println("sorry but that cannot be an input please enter another number between 20 and 30.");
            matches = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to return the `matches` value from your functions. And you can optimze your `computerTurn`-function.

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to my game of Nym");
    int playerFirst = 1;     //(int) (Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    int matches;
    if (playerFirst == 1) {
        System.out.println("This time the computer will go first.");
        System.out.println("You may choose the number of toothpicks, This number must be bigger than 20 and less than 30.");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        matches = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (matches <= 20 || matches > 29) {
            System.out.println("sorry but that cannot be an input please enter another number between 20 and 30.");
            matches = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.print(matches);
        do {
            matches = computerTurn(matches);
            matches = playerTurn(matches);
        } while (matches > 0);
    }
    if (playerFirst == 2) {

    }


}

public static int playerTurn(int matches) {
    System.out.print("How many toothpicks do you want to remove? ");
    int input = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = keyboard.nextInt();
    while (input<=0||input>=4){
        System.out.println("Please enter a number between 1 and 3: ");
        input=keyboard.nextInt();
    }
    if (input > 0 && input < 4) {
        matches=matches-input;
    }
    return matches;

}

public static int computerTurn(int matches) {
    int remove = 0;
    if (matches % 4 == 0) {
        remove = 3;
    } else if (matches % 4 == 3) {
        remove = 2;
    } else {
        remove = 1;
    }
    System.out.println("My turn. There are " + matches + " toothpicks left. I, the Computer, will remove " + remove + " of them.");
    matches -= remove;
    System.out.println("Your turn, there is " + matches + " toothpick left.");
    return matches;
}
```